# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'response' is undefined

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, jinja2

I am getting the above mentioned error when I try to iterate through elements of json output. 
This is my **app.py** file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

app = Flask(__name__)
es = Elasticsearch()
@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    q = request.form.get("q")
    if q is not None:
        resp = es.search(index='aman', body={"query": {"match":{"NAME": q}}})
        return render_template('index.html', q=q, response=resp)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my **index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="q"> search here : </label><input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="{{q}}">
        <input type="submit" value="search">

    <ol>
        {% for resp in response.hits.hits %}
        <li><a href="{{resp._source.url}}"> {{resp._source.NAME}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Surprisingly enough when I replace the content between ordered list tags with **{{response}}** The program runs without error and data in "response" variable is printed on the web page.
Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Posting solution since it might come handy for someone with similar issue.
 In **app.py** file replace **response=resp** with **response=resp["hits"]["hits"]**
and in **index.html** file, replace **response.hits.hits** with **response**.